# If you have $8$ shells, and $2$ of them have coins, what is the probability of guessing which have coins if you have $4$ guesses?

Tags: probability

> If you have $8$ shells, and $2$ of them have coins underneath them (you do not know which shells), what is the probability of guessing both the shells with coins underneath if you have $4$ guesses?

I got a little stumped on this one. It's the guesses that really throw me off. I originally thought 
$$\frac{2}{8}\cdot\frac27\cdot\frac26\cdot\frac15$$ would work, but that doesn't make sense to me because by that logic, if you had two guesses the probability would be 
$$\frac28\cdot\frac27.$$ Which would mean the probability with $4$ guesses is lower than the probability with $2$.

Comment: Hint: One way to think about this is to consider how many ways there are to guess "successfully" and how many ways there are to guess in total. Then just divide the number successful by the total.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 ways in which your two correct guesses can be arranged within your four guesses (eg first, second or first, third etc). For the first of these two guesses you have 2 ways to be correct and for the second just one. For the first of the incorrect guesses there are 6 possibilities and for the second 5. So in total you have $6\cdot2\cdot1\cdot6\cdot5=360$ ways out of a total of $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5=1680$. So the probability is $\frac{3}{14}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom84$ ways to select $4$ shells out of $8$.

There are $\binom62$ ways to select $4$ shells out of $8$ under the extra condition that $2$ specific shells (those with coins underneath) are selected. You could interpreted this as selecting $2$ shells out of the $6$ shells that have no coin underneath.

So the probability of this event is: $$\frac{\binom62}{\binom84}=\frac3{14}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the hypergeometric distribution, then you can think about it as follows.

Our scenario is like having $2$ two gold balls (which represent the coins), and $6$ silver balls (which represent empty shells) in a box. Notice that choosing four shells is like drawing from the box *without* replacement four times. There are two "good" balls, and six "bad" ones. There are $\binom22$ ways to choose the good ones, and we are forced to make two more choices. Hence there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose two bad ones. There are $\binom84$ ways to choose from the total. So, by the hypergeometric distribution, the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom62}{\binom84} = \frac{3}{14}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Look at it from the idea of correctly placing the two coins in the shells that you guessed. There are 8 shells. Four of them are guessed shells. Randomly place one of the coins under a shell.  You have a 4/8 probability of it being under a guessed shell. Assuming you were lucky, there are now 7 shells you can place the coin under and 3 that are guessed shells. to give you a 3/7 probability of placing the coin under a guessed shell. So the probability of both coins being under guessed shells is

$$
\frac{4}{8}*\frac{3}{7} = \frac{3}{14}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are six pairs within the four you guessed, out of 28 pairs altogether,  So your chance of winning is $$\frac{4\choose2}{8\choose2}=\frac6{28}=\frac3{14}$$